# Functional testing for windows metro application

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-metro, functional-testing

I would like to functionally test a windows metro app that was that was designed using Javascript.

I have done some online searching but couldn't find any recommendation for a good framework to handle it properly.

What are the best options currently available?

Comment: For web based application these are my suggestions
http://metroui.org.ua/ and 
http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/hub.html

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) but I also heard many good things about [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/). Basically any Javascript testing framework should do. In case you want to do acceptance testing, you can have a look at this [gist I put together](https://gist.github.com/milgner/4154841) where we use a modified version of [Cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) to formulate the tests.